# 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large) Vue + Springboot + SpringSecurity

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, spring-security

I'm receiving a 431 error when making an axios call to my backend in Springboot and I'm not sure why. My Vue frontend is running on port 3000 and my Tomcat server is on port 8080. Is there something I need to do to configure smaller headers?

Axios call -

```
  submit() {
    axios.post('/api/v1/auth/sign-in', {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password,
      staySignedIn: this.staySignedIn
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      if(res.data.code === 200) {
        this.router.push('/dashboard')
      }
      else {
        this.msg = response.message;
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      this.msg = 'error';
    })
  }
```

Login Controller -

```
@Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;


    @PostMapping("/sign-in")
    public String signIn(@RequestBody User user) {
        User userEmailExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());

        // Test
        if(userEmailExists.getEmail().isEmpty()) {
            return "Nothing";
        }
        else {
            return "SignIn";
        }
    }
}
```

My Security -

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/api/v1/auth/sign-in")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .and()
            .rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret");
            http.cors();
}
```

[image]

Comment: what does the request look like in the webbrowser console

Comment: @Toerktumlare Not sure what you mean, this is all I see in the console -      

POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign-in 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Comment: if you press F12 in the webbrowser and select "network" in chrome, you can see all requests, there you will find what your request and response looks like

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: @Toerktumlare I added a picture of it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your request is done against `localhost:3000` and not `localhost:8080` thats why you are getting the error.

if you are for example running a react app in the frontend and it is created by `create-react-app`

you can define a `proxy` in the `package.json`

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

And it will get picked upp by fetch automatically.

[proxy requests in a react app in development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

EDIT:

Saw now that you are using vue, i have no experience with vue.js but i did find a link to something [Vue.js — How To Proxy To Backend Server](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/vue-js-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-a562bad965eb)

Comment: I'm running Springboot

Comment: yes but not in the frontend, i saw that you are using vue, i have no experience with vue but i found some link that might help you. But as said, your request is going to the wrong place.

Comment: please mark this as the correct answer if you feel that it helped you